# Java / Generics / ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I have a `LinkedList<T>` which contains `Object toArray()` method:

```
public Object[] toArray()
{

    Object[] array = new Object[size];

    int c=0;
    for(Node<T> i = first;i != null;i=i.next)
    {
        array[c++] = i.data;
    }

    return array;
}
```

I would like to sort my LinkedList with a generic method: `<T extends Comparable> void sort (List<T> list)`. To sort lists, i must represent them as array in this method:

```
T[] elements = (T[])list.toArray();`
```

However, i get `ClassCastException` at this line and i don't know why. Since the generic type of the method equivalent to the element's runtime type in the returned array, this cast is not a lie!

Comment: could you provide more code please? its hard to tell anything like that

Comment: `List#toArray()` returns `Object[]`, not `T[]` (array keeps type of its elements, in this case it is `Object`). To sort a list, use `Collections.sort(list)`, or provide `T[]` in `toArray(T[] destination)`

Comment: Why not just sort the list without changing it to an array using java.util.Collections: `Collections.sort(list)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toArray()` returns `Object[]`. The type information is lost and you can't cast it back to T[]. If you want to keep the type information you can use the following. Then you give the method an predifined array which get filled. If you don't give anything - `toArray` will create a new `Object[]`.

```
T[] elements = list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```

just filling an array (another writing style):

```
T[] elements = new T[list.size()];
list.toArray(elements);
```

or if you use Java 8:

```
T[] elements = list.stream().toArray(T[]::new);
```

Comment: However, the complier says i cannot create generic array.

Comment: Of course, the T is only for demonstration. Outside, where you call the toArray method, you have to give a real type like String or Integer. Internally in the toArray method, the generics are used.

Answer (score 2):

The method `LinkedList.toArray()` creates a new array of the type `Object[]`. It does not create a new array of the type `T[]`. This is important, because even though the array only contains instances of `T`, you cannot assign the array to a variable of the type `T[]`, because the array itself has the type `Object[]`. You can reproduce this error with the following code:

```
String[] array = (String[]) new Object[0];
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert the list into an array to be able to implement your own search function. Given a `List<T>`, that contains elements of the type `T` you want to convert this list into an array of the type `T[]`. However, you cannot simply call `new T[list.size()]`, since Java looses the generic type information at compile time. To create the correctly typed array, you need to use the reflection method [`Array.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-).

Here is an example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] array = list.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size()));
    // sort array and write result to the list
}
```

And here the usage:

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    // populate the list
    sort(list, String.class);
    System.out.println(list); // -> the sorted list
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra work. I will do some further research in these stuff

Comment: Always happy to help. The keyword is **type erasure**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `T[] toArray(new T[list.size()])` instead. No need to cast.

Comment: @BenyBosko because `T[]` is "array of `T`s", not "array of `Object`s". Type erasure isn't applied.

Comment: But i thought the underlying type is T and not Object in the returned array! Sorry, it is not clear.

Comment: @BenyBosko this method appeared far before generics were introduced, when `List` was just `List`. Now it is impossible to change return type to `T[]` because of backward compatibility.